# Dialog Progress Bar during the process FirebaseAuthentication with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-progressbar

I create an android app with Kotlin.I use FireBase to authenticate. In the authentication UI,I woukd like to add a ProgressBar during the process FirebaseAuthentication i.e when I click on SignIn Button the progressBar appear until the authentication success. I create a constraint Layout that contains a Progress Bar as the following code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cp_bg_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 .....>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/cp_pbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/honey"
           ...... />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cp_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            .... />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

After click on button SignIn, in my authentication activity I put the code to inflate the layout with ProgressBar and then the FirebaseAuthentication with Email and Password :

```
     val dialog = Dialog(this)
        val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_progress_bar, null)
        dialog.setContentView(inflate)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
                ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
  fireBaseAuthentication = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
      fireBaseAuthentication.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                dialog.show()
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    fireBaseId = fireBaseAuthentication.currentUser!!.uid
                    .......
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "${task.exception?.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                Handler().postDelayed({dialog.dismiss()},3000)
```

And I get the following error :

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.app.honey.activity.user.authentication.Authentication has leaked
>   window DecorView@5287511[Authentication] that was originally added
>   here
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:511)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
>           at com.app.honey.activity.user.authentication.Authentication$signIn$1.onComplete(Authentication.kt:96)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.app.honey, PID: 2507
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=DecorView@5287511[Authentication] not attached to window manager
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:485)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:394)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:124)
>           at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:375)
>           at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:358)
>           at com.app.honey.activity.user.authentication.Authentication$signIn$1$1.run(Authentication.kt:103)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   I want to know what is the problem in my code and How can I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
val dialog = Dialog(this)
val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_progress_bar, null)
dialog.setContentView(inflate)
dialog.setCancelable(false)
dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
dialog.show()
fireBaseAuthentication = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
fireBaseAuthentication.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        ...
        finish()
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "${task.exception?.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

You must show the dialog before authenticating and dismiss it afterwards. Also, you can’t dismiss the dialog after transition between activities.

Comment: Your code work with no error, but after dialog dismiss the authentication activity still persist and it get a time to go to main activity

Comment: @Lina OK. You can not dismiss the dialog if result is successful. And after the transition to the main activity, call the method finish() at the authentication activity.

Comment: The problem when the call of  the finish() method,the activity finish and still wait a time to open the main activity, It's not a solution

Comment: @Lina Have you moved the dialog.dismiss() call to the else statement?

Comment: Still have a problem, ,the activity finish and still wait a time to open the main activity